# express-http-context for next js api

Tags: express, next.js, middleware

I need HTTP context for the next.js API

```
const httpContext = require("express-http-context");
app.use(httpContext.middleware);
httpContext.set("res", res);
```

Is there a way to use middleware in next.js 12 to get the same functionality where I can access the API response in any part of the server api